# Does JPARepository use method return type to find target table?

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

This seems to work, but I'd like someone to confirm this:

I have a base class BaseEntity for my entities.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseEntity {
...
}
```

I then have several entities, say A and B and C that extend from BaseEntity.
In addition, I have a single JPARepository defined as:

```
JPARepository<BaseEntity, Long>
```

Now it **looks like** I can use this repository to query tables A,B or C separately with simply changing the return type. For example:

```
public List<B> findBsByNameContaining(String name);
```

will result in a query that selects rows from table B only.

Is this really how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide a subtype of the type you declared at the repository interface level we will use that to execute the query against (read: essentially trigger `em.createQuery(typeReturnedByTheMethod)`). In case the returned type is *not* a subtype of the domain class managed by the repository, we'll still use the plain domain type.